# DOMElement cannot be converted

Tags: php, arrays, dom

I'm working on parsing an element using DOM, via class name. I'm using the following function to retrieve the information:

```
<?php function getElementsByClassName(DOMDocument $DOMDocument, $ClassName) {
    $Elements = $DOMDocument -> getElementsByTagName("*");
    $Matched = array();

    foreach($Elements as $node) {
        if( ! $node -> hasAttributes())
            continue;
            $classAttribute = $node -> attributes -> getNamedItem('class');

        if( ! $classAttribute)
            continue;
            $classes = explode(' ', $classAttribute -> nodeValue);

        if(in_array($ClassName, $classes))
            $Matched[] = $node;
    }

  return $Matched;
}

?>
```

Now, I'm using the $price array to store all of the information retrieved by getElementsByClassName():

```
$price = getElementsByClassName($doc, 'amount');

echo $price;
```

When echoing $price, it confirms my assumption that it is an array.

When using print_r($price);, the array is displays this, which holds 19 different variables, which is the exact ammount there should be:

```
Array ( [0] => DOMElement Object ( ) [1] => DOMElement Object ( ) [2] => DOMElement Object ( ) [3] => DOMElement Object ( ) [4] => DOMElement Object ( ) [5] => DOMElement Object ( ) [6] => DOMElement Object ( ) [7] => DOMElement Object ( ) [8] => DOMElement Object ( ) [9] => DOMElement Object ( ) [10] => DOMElement Object ( ) [11] => DOMElement Object ( ) [12] => DOMElement Object ( ) [13] => DOMElement Object ( ) [14] => DOMElement Object ( ) [15] => DOMElement Object ( ) [16] => DOMElement Object ( ) [17] => DOMElement Object ( ) [18] => DOMElement Object ( ) )
```

But, when I try to use this array as a string, I get this error:

```
echo $price[5];
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out why this can't be converted to a string? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that your function `getElementsByClassName` is completely unnecessary.

Retrieving all nodes that belong to a certain class with PHP's DOM library can be easily done with XPath.

For example, like this (assuming `$dom` is your DOM structure object):

```
$prices = array();

foreach((new DOMXPath($dom))->query('//*[@class="amount"]') as $price) {
   $prices[] = $price->nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Because a `DOMElement` is not a string and does not have a "magic" `__toString()` method.

First [Google result for "DOMElement php"](https://www.google.com/search?q=DOMElement+php) leads to the PHP documentation of [`DOMElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php), which is a sub class of [`DOMNode`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php). The latter has a `nodeValue` and a `textContent` property, so you could either try:

```
$priceValue = $price[5]->nodeValue
```

or

```
$priceValue = $price[5]->textContent
```

You could even go further and retrieve the actual text node child, but this is probably beyond what you need and would only complicate things (especially for read-only access).